# Using fully expanded result as a simple string (with citet and \IfSubStr)

Tags: macros, natbib, expansion, strings

I am breaking my head with that problem, without finding anything that could help on Internet :

The initial problem is that I write an essay in French but I need to include some articles written in English and thus different citation styles. As French is the main language, I use `unsrtnat-fr` bibliography style from `natbib` package, which produces citations as "Name1 **et** Name2" (two authors) using `\citet`. I would like to recover the normal style for given English parts "Name1 **and** Name". My solution is to define a custom command, let's say `\encitet`, which replaces *" et "* by *" and "* in the result of `\citet`.

I tried different definitions but finally I cannot understand how to do that... Each time there is a problem with argument expansion.

Here is the pseudo code of the command I would like to define :

```
\newcommand{\encitet}[1]{%
% 1 : store the result of \citet{#1} in tmp (as a simple string)
% 2 : test if 'et al.' is found into the string
% 3 : if found then return tmp 
% 4 : else return the replacement of every " et " by " and " in tmp
}
```

And here is the TeX file I use for my tests :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-fr}

% Here is the problem
\newcommand{\encitet}[1]{%
    \def\tmp{\expandafter\citet{#1}}%
    %\edef\tmp\expandafter{\mytemp{#1}}%
    %
    \expandafter\IfSubStr{\tmp}{et al.}{%
        \tmp%
    }{%
        \StrSubstitute{\tmp}{ et }{ and }%
    }\xspace%
}

% Example that works
\newcommand{\encitett}[1]{%
    \def\mytemp{\expandafter\citet{#1}}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{#1}{a}{"a" was given}{not a}, %
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\mytemp{#1}{b}{"b" was given}{not b}%
}


\begin{document}

% Example with two authors
\encitet{einstein}

% Example with more than two authors 
\encitet{latexcompanion}


\citep{knuthwebsite}


\medskip

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

and the bib file :

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein and AnotherGuy ForTheTest",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

And the compilation command :

```
pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex && bibtex test && pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex
```

I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. \citet is a much to complicated macro, you can't retrieve its output is a simple way. If you really want to stick to natbib  (in biblatex language support is build in)  you should manipulate the .bst-file. Save it under another name in your document folder and then change the fixed words so that they issue commands. E.g.

```
FUNCTION{fr.and}{       %% le "et" entre les deux derniers auteurs
" \authorand{} "
}
```

You can then give the commands sensible definitions in your document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but unfortunately the behaviour is not exactly what I expected. I did what you said but I cannot change the definition of `\authorand` in the document. When I use `\renewcommand` it keeps the last definition and when I put this renewcommand into a newly defined environment it is not taken into account. I want to keep french style by default and use english style some times in the doc, locally.

Comment: You should use \DeclareRobustCommand for the definition so that it doesn't get expanded when written to the aux-file.